# Cannot find module after using state syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the following error in my browser console:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./components/search_bar"

I am learning ReactJS and upon working on creating a very simple component, I stumbled upon the above error. It occurred after applying the `state` syntax in my `SearchBar` class/component. I am simply seeking on some enlightenment towards what is wrong, because I am not able to identify this after revising my code.

Please reference the below code:

## search_bar.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class SearchBar extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {term: ""};
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <input onChange={
                    event => this.setState({
                        term: event.target.value;
                    })
                }/>
                Value of input: {this.state.term}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

## index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import SearchBar from './components/search_bar';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <SearchBar />
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector(".container"));
```

Comment: If the module cannot be loaded anymore, you most likely have a syntax error. And here it is: `term: event.target.value;`.

Comment: you arent assigning a value to the input? `value={this.state.term}`

Comment: @FelixKling how can I fix that line of code friend?

Comment: @JohnRuddell originally I was attempting to replace `event => console.log(event.target.value)` by the above `state` syntax,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix the syntax error, (semicolon). also assign the value of your state to the input

```
<input 
  onChange={ event => this.setState({term: event.target.value}) }
  value={this.state.term}/>
```

Comment: this may sound extreme, but I am sure all of us developers should ask when we die: how much time combined did I waste looking for the missing/extra semi colon? Thanks for the help John!

Comment: Haha right? the semi colon, comma.. etc. fresh pair of eyes always does the trick :)